# Why does Xcode 4.1 installation ask me to close iTunes when it isn't open?

Tags: itunes, macos, xcode

I am trying to install xcode 4.1 with lion. Apparently at 3/4 of the installation problem, it says to close itunes, which is not open. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Use Activity Monitor, and locate the iTunes Helper process and kill it. As per an [Apple support discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15676913#15676913) and several other sources.

Update: The latest Xcode installer has been fixed and this should not be an issue now.

Comment: Yup. Also had to do this on a clean install of Lion for XCode to complete installing. It's a known bug in the installer that hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a bug in the `Install Xcode` 4.1 in regard to detecting that iTunes Helper is running. This has been fixed with `Install Xcode` 4.1.1 which you can get as a delta Update from the Mac AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem with Xcode as well. The solution I found was that iTunes was open in another account. iTunes must be quit in all acounts to complete the installation. Also make sure that you quit iTunes(command q)not just close all the windows. Those are the two most likely reasons for that error message.